# SDK manager did not open in my eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

```
[SDK Manager] The system cannot find the path specified.
```

while open sdk manager this message showed in console.

Comment: Set android SDK path from preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just go to windows-> preferences -> android and set the path of the sdk you have downloaded

[image]

Take a reference in the image

Answer (score 1):

It shows that the path you specified is  incorrect . First we need to download the android sdk as per our version requirements. Then place the downloaded sdk inside C:\ program files .............. .

Then run to eclipse and go to `windows/ preferences`and provided the path where you kept the sdk